# Iterating Row Operations in SQL

Tags: sql

I have a table filled with repetitive columns of the same measurement over a series of weeks (W1, W2, W3,...,W_N). Let's say I'm measuring rainfall in inches.

Having the data separated like this is a bit of a pain but necessary for some of the other reports tied to the data. I'd like to have the ability to aggregate W1 up to W_N for each row.

This should create a column at the end of my table, `TOTAL_RAINFALL`, that is the sum of W1 through W_N (W1+W2+W3+...W_N). For small N, this could literally be

```
SELECT 
    CITY,
    W1, W2, W3, W4,
    (W1 + W2 + W3 + W4) AS TOTAL_RAINFALL
FROM 
    WEATHER_DATA
```

However, for larger column volumes this can become annoying. Is there a better way to iterate through this process?

Comment: You might want to consider a different schema where one of your tables holds <city, week, rainfall> (for example) and then you can simply use the aggregate function sum() to get the total. (Plenty of examples on how to use sum are out there).

Comment: You could say  for the first line of the sql --  SELECT *   but for the second line what you have is probably the fastest when given the current schema.

Comment: Which [DBMS product](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DBMS) are you using? "SQL" is just a query language, not the name of a specific database product. Please add a [tag](https://stackoverflow.com/help/tagging) for the database product you are using `postgresql`, `oracle`, `sql-server`, `db2`, ...

Comment: The proper solution would be to normalize the data model

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you follow faintsignal's advice and convert your table schema from your current flat format to a transactional format.

I generally use excel-assisted SQL coding for such conversion exercises. The end goal is to generate a long series of UNION SELECT statements.

```
SELECT CITY, W1 AS RAIN INTO transactionalSchema WHERE W1 IS NOT NULL
UNION SELECT CITY, W2 WHERE W2 IS NOT NULL
UNION SELECT CITY, W3 WHERE W3 IS NOT NULL
etc...
```

Following this pattern, you can see it should be straightforward to generate all union selects you need with an excel formula looking at a base column with the values 1, 2, 3, 4, etc...

If column A is filled in with an incrementing value, you can use a formula like

```
="UNION SELECT CITY, W"&A1&" WHERE W"&A1&" IS NOT NULL"
```

in column B. Column B can then be copied and pasted back into a SQL editor.

You can then easily sum the values of RAIN for all cities using:

```
SELECT CITY, SUM(RAIN) AS TOTAL_RAINFALL FROM transactionalSchema GROUP BY CITY
```

Answer (score 0):

You didn't mention your DBMS, but in Postgres you could do the following:

```
select *, 
       (select sum(t.v::int) 
        from jsonb_each_text(to_jsonb(w)) as t(k,v)
        where t.k like 'w%') as total_rainfall
from weather_data w
```